# I get an error at first run of Yii1 application

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x, cexception

i am new to Yii. I am trying to setup a yii 1 app and i get this error.

"Application runtime path "C:\xampp\htdocs\gfs_design\protected\runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process."

I am using Xampp and the frontend and the yii folders are in my htdocs directory.
What I Have Done:

1. I have made the Yii folder writable from properties\security\advanced and so on

But i still get the error.

Can any one help?

Comment: Use chmod -R 777 /path/to/runtime folder as it should be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Since **runtime** folder should be publicly accessible, just use the following commands to make the folder writable/readable from the web:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/project/protected/runtime
chmod -R 777 /path/to/project/protected/runtime
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

JFYI, **runtime** directory is internally used by Yii framework to store some cached data, such as logs, session and assets.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The App didn't even have a runtime folder. Just creating the folder in protected helped.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The App didn't even have a runtime folder. Just creating the folder in protected helped.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime folder must have access to read write and also should be available for publically.

Please give permission to runtime folder

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/project/protected/runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time the app is installed, it doesn't come with a runtime directory.  Just creating the folder in protected helped.